# how to update multiple column in a single table

Tags: sql

I have created a table having three colums GsID,ALlowance and amount

```
Begin   if exists(select * from [dbo].[HRAllowances] where GdId=@GdId)  begin
        update [dbo].[HRAllowances]          set
             Amount=@Amount  where GdId=@GdId        end

end
```

this only works for one particular row..

i want to allow user to update amount for all rows

Comment: why don't you uset transaction..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to update all the rows than you have to remove where condition that is

`where GdId=@GdId` from you query.

Like this :-

```
update [dbo].[HRAllowances] set  Amount=@Amount
```

I hope it will works!!

Answer (score 4):

After seeing your comment, if you wish to update **all** `Amount` fields for all records, remove your `WHERE` clause as this is filtering records by ones where `GdId=@GdId`:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[HRAllowances]
SET Amount=@Amount
```

Comment: actully i want to update only amount fields i.e all amount colums at once